# Why the Key generated is always different even when the string to generate key is same in appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am new to google-app-engine and in the mid of developing a testing application I encountered a problem.
I am generating key using the user's email id to save the User Entity.

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("email",email );
```

Now on seeing  datastore viewer most part of the key is same just few last alphabets of the key are changed even when I am giving the same email id to generate the key.

Actually I was hoping to get the user entity by the key using the code.

```
Entity user = datastore.get(key);
```

But since the key is not the same as previous I am getting **noEntityFoundException**

**What I wanted to ask is why when the input is same the generated key is different every time.**

**Also if it is different every time how can I make it to generate the same key every time so that I can fetch the entity directly by that key?**

For more clarification : here is the [code](https://github.com/sioLabs/tambola.git)
The index.jsp is the welcome file. I create an user with an email id eg: abc@example.com.
This sends the form details to

```
com.siolabs.tambola.Createuser.java
```

**Createuser**  servlet checks if the email id exists. If not then save the info to the datastore.

[createUser code here](https://gist.github.com/3744326)

Then for login I submit the info on the index.jsp page. It forwards the request to 
    com.siolabs.tambola.Login.java
**Login Servlet** checks if the email id exists and if it does then forward the request to **home.jsp**  page.

[login servlet code](https://gist.github.com/3744347)

The problem is **login** servlet never finds the email-id as it is changed.

Thanks

Comment: My question is in regard to google-app-engine. 
I think I was unable to make the question understandable.What I wanted to ask is why when the input is same the generated key is different every time. 
Also if it is different every time how can I make it to generate the same key every time so that I can fetch the entity directly by that key.

Comment: how do you know that the key is not the same - have you compared two different values?

Comment: @mattb Yes, I have compared the values.Only the last few alphabets are same. Also I was trying to generate the key using the email-id and then using the "datastore.get(key)" and every time it gives "EntityNotFoundException"

Comment: I use the same code to generate keys and retrieve entities by the key all the time: it always returns the same key. Something else is wrong in your code. Add this to your code to troubleshoot: System.out.println("Created key for: " + key.getId()); Add it to the place where you create the key, and to the place where you try to use it. You should get the same id in both places (equal to you email variable).

Comment: @AndreiVolgin key.getId() is showing me 0 both the times.

Comment: Try this: Entity emailEntity = new Entity("email", email); Long id = datastore.put(emailEntity).getId();  What do you get?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin the value of id is **0** both the times. If it helps I am running the application on local machine.

Comment: Id of an entity cannot be zero. Something is wrong.

Comment: Yeah something is wrong... If it helps.I have uploaded the code on [github](https://github.com/sioLabs/tambola.git)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16842/discussion-between-t0mkaka-and-andrei-volgin)

Answer (score 0):

The createKey function takes two strings.

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("email",email);
```

Are you certain that the second email parameter is a string?  Most likely it's some other type that's being converted to a string incorrectly.

Comment: yeah checked with instanceOf(). Its a string. :-(